# Deleating a space in the command echo !D!>>server.properties

Tags: batch-file

My .bat file looks like this:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4 Address"') do (
set ip=%%a
goto :BREAK
)

:BREAK
echo %ip: =% >ip.txt
goto :Loopforcheck

:Loopforcheck
goto :Copy
if exist <ip.txt> (
    goto :Copy
) else (
    echo failed to find file
    goto :Loopforcheck
)

:Copy
for /F "delims=" %%i in (ip.txt) do (
set "D=server-ip=%%i"
  echo max-tick-time=60000> server.properties
  echo server-name=Unknown Server>> server.properties
  echo generator-settings=>> server.properties
  echo force-gamemode=false>> server.properties
  echo allow-nether=true>> server.properties
  echo gamemode=0 >> server.properties
  echo enable-query=false>> server.properties
  echo player-idle-timeout=0>> server.properties
  echo difficulty=1>> server.properties
  echo spawn-monsters=true>> server.properties
  echo op-permission-level=4>> server.properties
  echo announce-player-achievements=true >> server.properties
  echo pvp=true >> server.properties
  echo snooper-enabled=true>> server.properties
  echo level-type=DEFAULT>> server.properties
  echo hardcore=false>> server.properties
  echo enable-command-block=true >> server.properties
  echo max-players=20>> server.properties
  echo network-compression-threshold=256 >> server.properties
  echo resource-pack-sha1=>> server.properties
  echo max-world-size=29999984>> server.properties
  echo server-port=1>> server.properties
  echo !D!>>server.properties
  echo spawn-npcs=true>> server.properties
  echo allow-flight=false>> server.properties
  echo level-name=world>> server.properties
  echo view-distance=10>> server.properties
  echo resource-pack=>> server.properties
  echo spawn-animals=true>> server.properties
  echo white-list=false>> server.properties
  echo generate-structures=true>> server.properties
  echo online-mode=false>> server.properties
  echo max-build-height=256>> server.properties
  echo level-seed=assboobs>> server.properties
  echo enable-rcon=false>> server.properties
  echo motd=MINECRAFT BG>> server.properties
 )
  )
  goto :Exit

:Exit
TIMEOUT 3
Del ip.txt
java -Xmx3G -Xms3G -jar m.jar -o false
PAUSE
del server.properties
```

And my output server.properties is like this

```
max-tick-time=60000
server-name=Unknown Server
generator-settings=
force-gamemode=false
allow-nether=true
gamemode=0 
enable-query=false
difficulty=
spawn-monsters=true
announce-player-achievements=true 
pvp=true 
snooper-enabled=true
level-type=DEFAULT
hardcore=false
enable-command-block=true 
max-players=20
network-compression-threshold=256 
resource-pack-sha1=
max-world-size=29999984
server-port=
server-ip=192.168.2.100 <------ THERE IS A SPACE!
spawn-npcs=true
allow-flight=false
level-name=world
view-distance=10
resource-pack=
spawn-animals=true
white-list=false
generate-structures=true
online-mode=false
max-build-height=256
level-seed=assboobs
enable-rcon=false
motd=MINECRAFT BG
```

And i would like to remove the space! 
Becouse i get this error when i run my m.jar file
    Encountered an unexpected exception java.net.UnknownHostException: 
    192.168.2.100

Comment: I thing you put the space in this line `echo %ip: =% >ip.txt` . Try with `(echo(%ip: =%)>ip.txt`

Comment: The line `if exist <ip.txt>` cannot work, remove the `<` and `>` signs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo %ip: =%` removes any spaces, but `echo %variable% >ip.txt` inserts a new one. Attention: Removing the space before the redirection would solve it, but might get you into trouble with numbers. Alternative better syntax:

```
(echo %%ip: =%)>ip.txt
```

or

```
>ip.txt echo %ip: =%
```